# How can I change the datatype of a populated table column from int to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called AdminTest with a column CreatedBy set to an int. At this point I am not really concerned about the value. The value could be 1,2, or anything.

I want to change the column to a uniqueidentifier:

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AdminTest] ALTER COLUMN [CreatedBy] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL;
```

But this fails as expected.

Is there some way I could make this change. Perhaps with more than one SQL DDL statement? I would like to create a new Sequential GUID and then set the value of every row of my table to this new Sequential GUId. If the values are all the same then that's okay.

Right now the only way I can think of doing this is to. Drop the column, add the column and then set it to the new value. Does this sound reasonable and if so then how could I do this? Sorry my SQL knowledge is not very good. I just used the VS2013 GUI to try things so far. I know how to open the SQL Query window but not how to create a sequential ID and then set it.

Thanks

Comment: Sequential GUID huh?  Good luck in fantasy land.

Comment: @sam, why fantasy? Newsequntialid()

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: GUIDs are not sequential.  Read the documentation for the the function you mention... its not sequential.

Comment: It is sequantial.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx read the very first statement `Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated`

Comment: @sam - What do you mean? I'm using SQL Server 2012 with the NewSequentialID function that bases the ID on the machine clock so how can it not be sequential ?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Sequential means following each other back-to-back. The fact that something is greater than the other isn't really a sequence. 1, 5, 9, 13 is a sequence (1+4*n, so back-to-back values). 1, 23664, 23667, 3578543222, 456765433345676 is not really sequential.

Comment: In this context, sequential simply means following a logical order, not necessarily a sequence with no gaps.  I personally prefer to use the term incremental to avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right way. Just drop the current column and add new one with default as newsequantialid().

```
Alter table drop column createdby
Go

Alter table add createdby uniqueidentifier not null default (newsequantialid()) with values
Go
```

Comment: Not sure why this had -1, so I balanced it. But, perhaps mention something about the limitations of "sequental" guid's: `Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer since Windows was started. After restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range, but is still globally unique.`.

Comment: Depending on the size of the table (as measured by number of rows), you may want to add your uniqueidentifier column with another name and nullable, populate it in batches, switch it to non-null and do a column name swap.